# How to show $n^k log(n^k) = o(n^{log(n)}) $

Tags: asymptotics

Not sure how to show that $n^k log(n^k) = o(n^{log(n)}) $ where $o$ is little-Oh and $k$ is a constant.
I mean I really do not know how even to start. Any hints?

Comment: What is $k$ here, a constant?

Comment: @ClementC. exactly

Comment: For large enough $n$, you have $\log (n^k) \leqslant n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $k$ is assumed to be a constant, then you are basically comparing a polynomial growth ($n^{O(1)}$) to a superpolynomial one ($n^{\omega(1)}$).

An idea of the proof:

- $n^k\log(n^k) = k n^k\log n = o(n^{k+1})$
- $(k+1)\log n = o(\log^2 n)$
- $n^{k+1} = 2^{(k+1)\log n}$, while $n^{\log n} = 2^{\log^2 n}$